# AJAX data uploading but not storing in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

please help me! i'm uploading multiple data with ajax request and data is uploading and i get response 200 OK but there's no data stored into database. here's my store method.

```
$data = json_decode($request["final_json"], true);
$data_to_insert = [];
        
        foreach($data as $request){ 
            
                $data_to_insert = [
                 'office_name' => $request['office_name'],
                 'registration_number' => $request['registration_number'],
                 'owner' => $request['owner_name'],
                 'father_name' => $request['father_name'],
                 'address' => $request['address'],
                 'vehicle_class' => $request['vehicle_class'],
                 'insurance_type' => $request['insurance_type'],
                 'insurance_company_name' => $request['insurance_company_name'],
                 'insurance_from' => $request['insurance_from'],
                 'insurance_up_to' => $request['insurance_up_to'],
                 'policy_number' => $request['policy_number'],
                ];
          }
       DB::table('owners')->updateOrInsert(['chasis_number' => $request['chasis_number']], $data_to_insert);
```

request is complete and it takes time too depending how much data i upload but in database there's not a single row get inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume $data_to_insert should be an array, you had defined the $data_to_insert before the foreach loop, which is great. However, in your foreach loop, you keep reassign new values to overwrite the previous value. You could try this instead:

```
foreach($data as $request){ 
    $data_to_insert = [
        'office_name' => $request['office_name'],
        'registration_number' => $request['registration_number'],
        'owner' => $request['owner_name'],
        ...
    ];
    DB::table('owners')->updateOrInsert(['chasis_number' => $request['chasis_number']], $data_to_insert);
}
```

I am not sure what is your intention, whether you have an array of items you want to store in DB, or you only have 1 object you want to store in DB. If there is only one object to be stored, you shouldn't use the foreach loop. If you could provide more details then I could answer more

Comment: I'm storing so many JSON objects. that's why I used foreach. and inserting data out of foreach. because in inside of foreach data storing is taking too much time which gives me different kinds of server errors like timeout or connection reset.

Comment: it's like from the code that i have now is giving me an empty array at the end. it is loading full data but at the end i only get an empty array to store.